# Gtk# references "disappear" when switching to Mono runtime in Monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I installed the following on my Windows 7 PC in the following order with no issues:
1.) Mono for Windows 2.10.5
2.) Gtk# for .Net 2.12.10
3.) Monodevelop 2.6 RC1

I made a simple test Gtk app (targeting .NET 3.5) to verify my new installation, and I noticed the following wierd behavior:

When I target the default runtime (Microsoft .NET), everything works fine.
[image: default runtime reference list]

However, when I change the target runtime to Mono, 
[image: runtime options]

all of my Gtk# references disappear, as shown in the next image.
[image: mono runtime missing references]

All of the references highlighted in red in image #3 have the same error message as the one I expanded for atk-sharp - "Assembly not available for Mono/.Net 3.5"

When I tried to correct the references using "Edit References", none of the Gtk# assemblies show up in the list of Packages when the runtime is Mono (remember, everything's fine when I target the default .NET). If I try to add the assemblies manually through the "Edit References" -> ".Net Assembly" dialog, I get a warning about losing my Stetic, then my UI gets blown away and the program will not compile/build anymore.

I tried changing my target runtime to .NET 4.0, 3.0, and 2.0, and that didn't make an ounce of difference:
[image: .Net2.0 didn't work, either]

I don't pretend to be an expert in the Mono world - is this a known issue? Did I miss a configuration step in my installation, perhaps? Thanks in advance - I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be encountering this bug:
http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=552

Comment: Thanks, man - you're probably right. I did find that I can "Run" -> "Run With" -> "Mono 2.10.5" and everything works. Am I right in assuming that this runs my program against the Mono runtime?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can build using .NET and run on Mono, and vice versa.

Comment: I ended up going back to Mono 2.6.7 and everything works fine now.